# Trying to get image in a custom UIButton to display full size?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I've added a Custom UIButton in Interface Builder and created the outlet in the view controller.

In my viewDidLoad I'm trying...

```
[photoButton setImage:managedObject.relatedImage.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[photoButton.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeRight];
```

It is completely ignoring my setContentMode part and always putting aligning it left and resizing the height to the size of UIButton height...

What I want is for it to display full size and whatever is outside the UIButton frame to just get cut off...  anyone know what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `photoButton.imageView` is an `UIImageView` and it does not have a method `setContentMode:`, according to [Apple Official Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIImageView) on that class.

I belive you don't have a button behaviour already coded for what you need. I'd suggest you to subclass the `UIButton` class (or a `UIView`) and create your own drawing function.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up putting a UIImageView underneath a blank UIButton in order to get it to work...

Then used:

```
[photoImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[photoImageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```